# How to deal with multiple features in a single git repository in QA

Tags: git

So I'm running into an issue with us trying to test multiple features in our QA environment at the same time. Essentially, changes are taking too long to get promoted in our CI/CD pipeline.

The way we have it set up now, we push feature branches directly into our QA environment if the build passes. We're using docker so we push the containers into that environment. With several changes in a single service being ready it's hard to manage them all being promoted.

Let's say someone promotes feature A to QA and they run into a problem. Then feature B gets blocked because A is in QA. Now, I have ideas about how to solve this but there are problems with them.

The solution I commonly see is to use a common branch that has both A and B in it. The issue with this is that feature A still has to be fixed before it can get released. So even if feature B works in QA and can be promoted, the build contains A and B. Based on the immutability of containers, I can't promote this build into production. I would have to redeploy something with only feature B to get it into production, and thus I have removed A and they can no longer debug their issue in QA.

Another solution I have is that we could just hold off on releasing and push all of them to production together. The issue with that is that if there's an issue in production, we have to revert several changes together. We effectively go back to the last stable build. Since we have a microservice architecture that might involve us reverting several services to effectively rollback. More frequent production deployments seems like a better strategy but I can't come up with a good solution to this problem. Sure, you can revert a change and test out a build in a reasonable amount of time, but the rollback still has to happen in the meantime.

I'm really not sure what approaches people have to this issue. I can't think of a good solution but I'm sure others have encountered this issue before.

Answer (score 2):

If your features are taking a long time to get into the main QA branch, that may be a symptom of your features being too big.  Smaller incremental improvements can help a lot.  However, there are also options depending on what you are using for your CI/CD tooling.

The ideal scenario is to have your CI tool to build and run all unit tests on every push:

- Commits to branches
- Pull requests
- Merges

If you have a large feature you can't break down, then the team working on that feature branch should probably regularly pull form the main dev stream just to avoid any integration surprises.

The real challenge then comes when you have multiple pieces to your overall solution and your automated test suite requires an environment to run against.  Those are typically more difficult to spin up and down.  That's where tools like [Chef](https://www.chef.io/) and [Salt](https://www.saltstack.com/) (or your equivalent) can spin up environments long enough to run your automated testing, and then tear them back down when you are done to free up resources.  Another option is to explore using containers.

The bottom line is that there is no simple answer, and you have to weigh the costs of setting up and running a fully automated environment vs. limiting the builds as you are doing now.  Sometimes it is very much worth the effort, but not all the time.

Comment: The features themselves are only taking too long to get into QA because other features are blocking them. We actually in-house developed our own tool to spin up environments but we still maintained it had to be deployed to our QA environment before prod. Part of that was fake data vs real data for testing. And our infrastructure is docker + k8.

The problem we have is that changes are living in QA too long for whatever reason, whether it's getting PR, testing, fixing bugs, etc. Outside of getting people to move faster I don't know how to avoid QA builds living too long and blocking things.

Comment: If you know a feature isn't good in the pull request, it gets rejected and _should_ have no impact on any other feature.  If there's a dependency, then you still may need to think about how you are splitting your features up.

Comment: It's not in a pull request. What happens is we have a branch ready to go into QA but for whatever reason it doesn't work in QA. Since it works locally the developer has to indefinitely tie up QA while they're debugging the issue. As for dependencies, that's a product of us having an environment with several microservices. A feature might span different services and so it requires multiple deployments to QA. It's essentially all about tying up the resource of the QA environment.

Answer (score 0):

[Gitflow is the answer for you](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow).

You'll basically have 2 main branches: master and develop. You'll promote develop to QA, and master to prod. For any specific features, create other branches. Once they are ready (code reviewed, unit testing ok), merge the feature branch to develop.

Develop should be tested in QA, and once everything is OK, merged into master. Now, there are several ways to deal with features that should be taken off the release, but the easiest way is to just remove it with another pull request, then do regression testing. If you are working in sprints, if they are short (let's say, 2 weeks), your development efforts are going to be short enough for this not to be a big issue. If your development time is longer, then you may need to do proper *testing cycles*.

Comment: When we promote the development branch to master/prod, it might require a lot of regression testing if we have to remove a bunch of things. And for whatever period of time we've removed certain things, our QA environment is missing features that others might be testing against. The issue was kind of that we needed multiple features in QA at a time. It's also not easy to remove a bunch of things when you have several microservices needing to remove features to accomodate.

Comment: Got it. Since you are using containers, then maybe an option could be to have addionals environments for this. It is always a bit complicated to hadle deliveries to QA, it might just come to what is available to your team.

Comment: I'm not sure what extra environments solve if we agree that it has to go through a single pre-production environment. That singular environment is still the bottleneck. The issue is still that I need multiple features in single environment simultaneously but I can't promote all of them to prod. Containers are really actually quite bad for this because of the immutability of them. I have to deploy a new container with the new changes before it goes to master/prod and that kicks out all the other features.

Comment: No solution is going to be painless. You need to determine what works for you and decide what yo use. The best approach is still to use a single, develop, branch with several features, fix if anything breaks, then do some regression.